# HTML/Javascript getting the current browser window and close it with timeout

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on a little script for greasemonkey, that should submit a form from another page (so the action attribute is different from the page where I want to submit it). The page where I want to include the script ist something like www.pennergame.de/overview/ and the form element calls a form-action from www.pennergame.de/stock/foodstuffs/use/

When I click on a input button, the form element will be submitted.
What I now want, is that the page does not redirect to the /stock/foodstuffs/use/ Page.

so, I want to 
1. submit the form element
2. open a new window with the /overview/ link AND close the current window OR stop redirecting to /stock/foodstuffs/use/

I tried this:

```
var overviewLink = 'http://www.pennergame.de/overview/';
var input_drink = document.createElement("input");
input_drink.type = 'submit';
input_drink.id = 'drink_Brot';
input_drink.value = 'Nüchtern werden (' + anzBrot + ' Brot essen)';
form.onsubmit = function (){ window.setTimeout('window.close()', 600); var fenster = window.open(overviewLink, '_blank'); };
```

What actually happens is: the form is submitted, the new window will be opened, but the old window won't be closed

And please, only JavaScript solutions when possible ;-)

Comment: `window.setTimeout(window.close, 600);`

Answer (score 0):

Dennis, I'm not sure if I understand your issue right, but let me describe what I've got from your message (correct me if wrong).
You want to do something on the current page (like pressing a button) and so invoke form submitting on another page.
Additionally it's needed to prevent a new window appearance.

1. You should not use the Window object to solve the problem. First because it's impossible to completely hide a window. And there is no way to close current window because only the windows created with window.open(URL) method are closeable.
2. Use `<iframe>` to open child pages. It is easy to operate (including hiding from user)
3. Try the following script by steps (push the buttons) to see what's going on:

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="createFrame();">createFrame</button>
  <button onclick="fillFormOnAnotherPage();">fillFormOnAnotherPage</button>
  <button onclick="submitFormOnAnotherPage();">submitFormOnAnotherPage</button>
  <button onclick="closeFrame();">closeFrame</button>
  <script>
    var frame
      , frameDoc
      , frameForm

    function createFrame()
    {
      frame = document.createElement( "iframe" );
      frame.src = 'prev.html'
      frame.setAttribute( 'hidden', '' ); // on debug remove this line to see the frame
      document.body.appendChild( frame );
    }

    function fillFormOnAnotherPage()
    {
      // document object of the page where we are looking for the form
      frameDoc = frame.contentDocument

      // somehow find your form
      frameForm = frameDoc.getElementById( 'myFormId' )

      // yes we can access form elements by their names
      var someInputElement = frameForm['myInputName']

      // just put all the data you want to the form elements
      someInputElement.value = "Greetings from another page"
    }

    function submitFormOnAnotherPage()
    {
      frameForm.submit();
    }

    function closeFrame()
    { // if you really need a closing with timeout just wrap this function with setTimeout
      document.body.removeChild( frame );
    }

    // call this method from console or script to do all the magic
    function doEverything()
    {
      createFrame()
      fillFormOnAnotherPage()
      submitFormOnAnotherPage()
      closeFrame()
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Here is preview.html (page to open in frame)

```html
<body>
<form id="myFormId">
    <input value="fancy" name="myInputName"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: P.S. I see you use a string as the first argument in setTimeout. It's unsafe old style (deprecated for now). You can pass an anonymous function as the first argument like this

`setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Hallo"); }, 800)`